# GUI not running properly

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am using mac OS X python. I'm working with GUI right now and is making a simple window with three buttons. I'm trying to configure some buttons to make them do something but it is not working. Can anyone tell me what the problem is? So far I have a little window with three buttons. I wrote the code:

```
 win=Tk()
 f=Frame(win)
 b1=Button(f,text="one")
 b2=Button(f,text"two")
 f.pack()
 def but1() : print "Button one was pushed"
 b1.configure(command=but1)
```

I am getting the error message invalid syntax for that.

Comment: Could you show your entire code?

Comment: which line you have error on?

Comment: win=Tk() 
b1= Button(win, text="One")
b2= Button(win,text="Two")
b1.pack()
def but1() : print"Button one has been pushed"
b1.configure(command=but1)

Comment: You need a working minimal example.   See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  I'd recommend editing your question  and including the example, not putting it in the comments.

Comment: I have added the edit to my original question. I'm still not understanding what you mean by the minimal example.

Comment: Can you give us the entire error message?

Comment: Include all of the relevant lines of code needed to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs to call `root.mainloop()` on the last line.  You also have the problem that you aren't calling `pack` or `grid` on the buttons. After adding the call to `mainloop()` you'll just see any empty window until you call `pack` or `grid` on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I see wrong with your code is that you forgot to include `=` when you define `b2`.  Running exactly what you have written will raise a Syntax Error.

```
from Tkinter import * 

win = Tk()
f = Frame(win)
b1 = Button(f, text="one")
b2 = Button(f, text="two") # Don't forget the equals sign.
f.pack()
def but1(): 
    print "Button one was pushed"
b1.configure(command=but1)
```